# JVM Crash in VLCJ based recording application

Tags: java, vlc, jna, vlcj, jvm-crash

I have a recording application which uses vlcj. Usually application works fine, without ant problem. But sometimes it crashes. I have following crash error:

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:   javaw.exe
>
> Application Version:    8.0.31.13
>
> Application Timestamp:  54926713
>
> Fault Module Name:  StackHash_fd70
>
> Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
>
> Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
>
> Exception Code: c0000005
>
> Exception Offset:   PCH_F6_FROM_ntdll+0x0000000000096B2A
>
> OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
>
> Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional Information 1:   fd70
>
> Additional Information 2:   fd708418e0c0196a5239016586aeb518
>
> Additional Information 3:   be53
>
> Additional Information 4:   be534f1b8c904d81a83bb96df947b1c7

Sometimes this project works 2-3 days without crash, but sometimes crashs after 4-5 hour. I restarted project every day, but this doesn't help.

I use java 8, VLC 2.2.0, vlcj 3.0.1, jna 3.5.2

Comment: You need to look at the native Hotspot JVM crash dump, and include it in your question.

Comment: where I can find dump files?

Comment: There is no dump files not in java home, bin directoriries, nor in project working directory